# Why doesn't implicit conversion work here?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, implicits

Given,

```
trait GetOrElseAble[Container[_]] {
  def getOrElse[A](one : Container[A], two : A) : A
}
```

And,

```
implicit val optionGetOrElseAble = new GetOrElseAble[Option] {
  override def getOrElse[A](one: Option[A], two: A): A = one.getOrElse(two)
}
```

And,

```
trait GetOrElseOp[A,F[_]] {
  val evidence : GetOrElseAble[F]
  val value : F[A]
  def |(other : A) : A = evidence.getOrElse(value,other)
}
```

And finally the implicit def,

```
implicit def toGetOrElseOp[A,F[_]](f : F[A])(implicit e : GetOrElseAble[F])  = new GetOrElseOp[A,F] {
  override val evidence = e
  override val value = f
}
```

Following works:

`toGetOrElseOp(None)(optionGetOrElseAble) | 100`

However, `None | 100` does not work.

According to my understanding, the `implicit def` should have kicked in, converted `None` to the type `GetOrElseOp` and the above should have worked.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Copy pasting this works for me. Using Scala 2.11.8

Comment: also works with scala 2.12.3: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/xEYvDwv/0

Comment: Don't forget to add `scalacOptions += "-language:implicitConversions"` to build.sbt.

Comment: Werid, It does work in all shells, but not in intellij scala worksheet with scala 2.11.8